# App with both Swift 3 and Objective-C crashes only on iPhone SE

Tags: ios, crash

I'm developing an app using both Swift 3 and Objective-C.

I keep getting the following crash only on iPhone SE:

```
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
-[_TtGCs26_SwiftDeferredNSDictionarySSP__ length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17022b880
```

This is the stack trace:

```
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x18d6aefe0 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x18c110538 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x18d6b5ef4 __methodDescriptionForSelector
3  CoreFoundation                 0x18d6b2f54 ___forwarding___
4  CoreFoundation                 0x18d5aed4c _CF_forwarding_prep_0
5  UIKit                          0x193cdac38 -[UIButton _updateTitleView]
6  UIKit                          0x193856be4 -[UIButton tintColorDidChange]
7  UIKit                          0x193cf4e40 -[_UITintColorVisitor _visitView:]
8  UIKit                          0x193cf5524 _UIViewVisitorEntertainVisitors
9  UIKit                          0x193cf4658 _UIViewVisitorRecursivelyEntertainDescendingVisitors
10 UIKit                          0x193cf4708 _UIViewVisitorRecursivelyEntertainDescendingVisitors
11 UIKit                          0x193cf3fa4 _UIViewVisitorEntertainDescendingTrackingVisitors
12 UIKit                          0x1937db964 __45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke
13 Foundation                     0x18e0e8a7c -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:]
14 UIKit                          0x1937db76c -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]
15 UIKit                          0x1937e7668 -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:]
16 UIKit                          0x1937e6f84 -[UIView(Hierarchy) addSubview:]
17 UIKit                          0x193ac4c84 -[UIView _setTraitStorageSubviews:]
18 Foundation                     0x18e0c364c -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:]
19 UIKit                          0x193addfe0 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) setValue:forKey:]
20 UIKit                          0x193c63fb8 -[_UIRelationshipTraitStorage applyRecordsMatchingTraitCollection:]
21 UIKit                          0x193c62968 -[NSObject(_UITraitStorageAccessors) _applyTraitStorageRecordsForTraitCollection:]
22 UIKit                          0x193ac87cc -[UIView _traitCollectionDidChangeFromOldCollection:toNewCollection:scaleDidChange:]
23 UIKit                          0x193ac88f0 -[UIView _wrappedProcessDidChangeRecursivelyFromOldTraits:toCurrentTraits:scaleDidChange:forceNotification:]
24 UIKit                          0x194140340 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _withUnsatisfiableConstraintsLoggingSuspendedIfEngineDelegateExists:]
25 UIKit                          0x193ac8b54 -[UIView _processDidChangeRecursivelyFromOldTraits:toCurrentTraits:forceNotification:]
26 UIKit                          0x1937dd00c -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:]
27 QuartzCore                     0x1909cd274 -[CALayer layoutSublayers]
28 QuartzCore                     0x1909c1de8 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)
29 QuartzCore                     0x1909c1ca8 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)
30 QuartzCore                     0x19093d34c CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*)
31 QuartzCore                     0x1909643ac CA::Transaction::commit()
32 QuartzCore                     0x190964e78 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*)
33 CoreFoundation                 0x18d65c9a8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
34 CoreFoundation                 0x18d65a630 __CFRunLoopDoObservers
35 CoreFoundation                 0x18d65aa7c __CFRunLoopRun
36 CoreFoundation                 0x18d58ada4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
37 GraphicsServices               0x18eff4074 GSEventRunModal
38 UIKit                          0x193845058 UIApplicationMain
39 <MyApp>                        0x10004fc5c main (main.m:14)
40 libdyld.dylib                  0x18c59959c start
```

Does anybody know what could be the cause of this kind of crashes?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your code from where your app is crashed?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any reference to the exact portion the code involved in the crash... it seems an internal UIKit/Foundation problem caused by some wrong type cast.
I wasn't able to find any reference to this kind of _NSInvalidArgumentException_ in my previous searches.

Comment: Does it happen when perform any kind of activity or doing any process?

Comment: Show [UIButton _updateTitleView]

Comment: @Nirmalsinh: From the user report, the best guess is for the crash to happen on screen loading process.

Comment: @サンディープ: I didn't override any _updateTitleView_ method, this is the standard UIKit's implementation.

Comment: Ah,did u integrate any 3rd party library ?

Comment: @サンディープ: We integrate Fabric 1.6.11, Crashlytics 3.8.3 and AFNetworking 3.1.0 with CocoaPods, and we still have some old reference to Google Analytics that needs to be cleaned up.

Comment: ok,enable zombie and update

Comment: did you try to clean and build the project again? I had a similar issue like this

Comment: The crash is kind of random, but it happens only on iPhone SE in when the user installs the app from the Store. Unfortunately I won't be able to have more detailed infos about the crash.

Comment: Best guess: a memory management problem.  Something calls a `length` method, likely believing it has a pointer to a string.  The string (or whatever) has been deallocated and its memory reassigned to an internal Swift object.